# Sending Telegram messages with Telethon

Tags: telethon

How to automatically send messages with a picture to all chat, channels in which you are a member? Or by the list of chats from the file. And so that it does not send it to ordinary users who write to you. And you could set the delay time for sending messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first three lines of the documentation show how to send a message:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
```

This answers the question in the title. For the rest, see [`client.iter_dialogs`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.iter_dialogs), the [`Dialog`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.dialog.Dialog) type, and [`client.send_file`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file). All links have examples.